# Custom related list button is not working in partner portal

Tags: partner-communities

I have created custom button called "New Employee" on employee object and it is related with both account and contact objects via lookup relation. If i click on "New Employee" button on employee related list under Account detail page, working fine in both salesforce classic and lightning experience but not in partner portal.

```
/a03/e?CF00N342300009cAB8={!Account.Name}&CF00N342300009cAB8_lkid={!Account.Id}&CF00N90000009cUVB={!Contact.Name}&CF00N90000009cUVB_lkid={!Contact.Id}&retURL={!Account.Id}
```

Any help on this.

Comment: Can you provide an error message or a better explanation of what does happen when you click on the button in the partner portal? My best guess is permissions and configurations.

Comment: If i click on button in parter portal nothing is happen (no action).

Comment: Are there any javascript errors in the browser dev console?

Comment: @gNerb I am also facing same issue. custom list URL Button is not working Partner Portal, But its working in Classic and lIghtning. What are the permissions and Configurations i need to do.

Comment: @Sfdcprgmr , did you get any solution for this please?

Answer (score 0):

If your community url isn't at the root then this relative url will not work.  i.e. if you community is on /partner/ then the link will not resolve correctly.. You will either need your community to sit on the root or change the button to work in a non-relative fashion.  You can find this setting in the community workspace administration under settings.