# I have created List custom button for student__c object classic and lightning working fine but not working partner community

Tags: partner-communities

I have created custom button called "New Employee" on employee object and it is related with both account and contact objects via lookup relation. If i click on "New Employee" button on employee related list under Account detail page, working fine in both salesforce classic and lightning experience but not in partner portal.

/a03/e?CF00N342300009cAB8={!Account.Name}&CF00N342300009cAB8_lkid={!Account.Id}&CF00N90000009cUVB={!Contact.Name}&CF00N90000009cUVB_lkid={!Contact.Id}&retURL={!Account.Id}

Comment: Please edit your original post and explain what is not working and include any error messages.

Comment: @David Cheng  thank for your reply i update the question please check once

Comment: What rights those objects have on the partner portal? Have you check all rights?

Comment: This is the exact same question as this one:  https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/240000/custom-related-list-button-is-not-working-in-partner-portal  Are you creating duplicate user IDs to post questions?